# File not found Exception in Android but File Exists

Tags: android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to get the address of any file on android and then read its content.

I am getting the location of file as :

```
uri2.toString() gives string "file:///storage/emulated/0/download/user.txt"

uri2.getEndodedPath() gives string "/storage/emulated/0/download/user.txt"
```

when passing these value to file it gives file not found exception

**Note : I am not reading file from sdcard or asset folder or raw folder and i am testing my app on mobile one plus cyanogen mod**

here is my android code

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainSpeechActivity extends Activity {

    TextToSpeech tts;
    Button btn;
    private String uri;
    private Uri uri2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_speech);


        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if(Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)){
            //uri = intent.getStringExtra("URI");
            uri2 = intent.getData();
            uri = uri2.getEncodedPath() + "  complete: " + uri2.toString();
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText(uri);
            // now you call whatever function your app uses

            String str = uri2.toString();// value is mentioned above
            File f = new File(str);
            BufferedReader br = null;
            String line;
            StringBuilder sbr = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f)));
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sbr.append(line);
                    sbr.append("\n");

                }
                br.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FileNotFound",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"InputError",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(sbr.toString().isEmpty())
                textView2.setText("Blah blah");
            else
            textView2.setText(sbr.toString());




        } else {
            Log.d("know", "intent was something else: " + action);
        }

        tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if( i != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                }
            }
        });

        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String toSpeak = "My friend is very good programmer do you aggree";

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),toSpeak,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                tts.speak(toSpeak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_speech, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**If reading file from android is not possible then how to copy that file to sdcard or at location where reading and writing is possible**

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to get the address of any file on android and then read its content.

> I am not reading file from sdcard

Then your options are fairly limited. The only way you can read a file from internal storage is if your app is allowed to access that part of internal storage.

---

However, seeing that you're trying to read from downloads, it should be fine. I think the problem is your file path is badly formatted:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/download/user.txt
```

Should just be

```
/storage/emulated/0/download/user.txt
```

which you have the value of, you just need to set your `str` variable to `getEncodedPath` instead of `toString`

Comment: problem solved just has to give appropriate <uses-permission> in android manifest.xml. i dont remember now.